# JavaScript: "Dynamic" back reference RegExp replacement

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I want to make replacements like this:

```
var txt = "Some text containing $_variable1 and with $_variable2 inside of it as well.";
var rx = /(\$_[a-z]+)/g

var $_variable1 = "A CAT";
var $_variable2 = "A HOTDOG";

var replaced_txt = txt.replace(rx, $1);
```

I want `replaced_txt` to equal "...containing A CAT and with A HOTDOG ins...", but the only way to achieve this that I've found so far is this:

```
var replaced_txt = txt.replace(rx, function($1){return eval($1)});
```

And I have a feeling this is not the most elegant solution, no?

Preferably I'd like to avoid `eval()`

I'm grateful for any ideas on this!

/C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var values = {
  '$_variable1': 'A CAT',
  '$_variable2': 'A HOTDOG'
};
var replaced_txt = txt.replace(rx, function(_, varName) {
  return values[varName] ? values[varName] : '<unknown variable: ' + varName + '>';
});
```

Comment: Seems right. I'm pretty sure `values[var] || 'default'` would be neater here, and `var` may not be the best variable name (does it work?)

Comment: ... and yes you could do the || thing but I was trying to be clear for pedagogical reasons.